# How to add dynamic css class with active property attached to button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, anchor

How to add following css class dynamically to a button.

```
.custom-button:active{
    background-image: url('images/pressed.jpg') !important;
}
```

i created a lot of buttons in java-script using the following code. The buttons already have a class .custom-button button without the property (active).

```
var ItemsToAdd = '';
ItemsToAdd += '<a id="' + id + '" data-role="button" style="background-image:url('+ img_path_normal +');border-width:0px;" class="custom-button" ></a>';                
$("#container2").append(ItemsToAdd);
```

the class that i already added using java script is following:

```
.custom-button {
    height: 150px !important; 
    width: 120px;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    border:0px;
    border-radius:0px;
    border-style:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border-width:0px;
}
```

Comment: You could try using jQuerys addClass(). `$("#"+id).addClass(".custom-button:active");`

Comment: pseudo class can't be added using `.addClass()`. you should refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

Comment: Can i add the active property to the class using style property in javascript ?

Comment: Why do you need to define this dynamically? Why not just put this in your stylesheet?

Comment: You can't force a certain pseudo-class to apply using jQuery or javascript.

Comment: @kei: I want to change the pressed state of the button by replacing the background-image url. Normall i do it using css. but now i need to create a lot of buttons using a loop in javascript and every button has its own image url (actually two urls one for the pressed and the other for normal state)

Comment: I tried to use vmousedown and vmouseout events to change the url but its not working fine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/6cg4u/

Comment: @Omar: your code does not work when i click and move the mouse out of the button area and then release.

Comment: just add `mouseleave` and it will work. note that on touch devices `mouseleave` wont trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can use addClass() to add any class to an HTML element.

Set up the CSS you want to add like so:

```
.custom-button-active{
    background-image: url('images/pressed.jpg') !important;
}
```

Notice I changed it to .custom-button-active, so it doesn't use a pseudo class (since there is no need for it). Now, when you want this style to apply to a button simply add that class to the button.

```
button.addClass('custom-button-active');
```

Now, the button will have that class in addition to any other classes you already gave it, and will use the appropriate styles.

Answer (score 1):

As it was stated above, you can't directly work with pseudo-classes in JavaScript. However, you can just change your stylesheet from inside Javascript code. Something like this:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('.custom-button:active { background-image: url('images/pressed.jpg') !important; }', 0);
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.backgroundColor= 'red';
```

or

```
var element = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(element);
var s = element.sheet;
s.insertRule('.custom-button:active {background-image: url("images/pressed.jpg") !important;}', s.cssRules.length);
```

More information about that syntax here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet.insertRule